# Why SAML is not preferred for SPA (built using Angular and WebAPI 2.0) in Okta?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, openid, saml, okta

I am exploring the Okta integration for my Single Page Application built using Angular 6 and Asp.net WebAPI2.0. On Okta I can see only OpenID connect as the only way to create the app.

So I have a doubt that why SAML is not a preferred way for SPA application on Okta

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

SAML is via browser redirect not REST API and it gives you an XML SAML token not a JWT OAuth token which means you can't use it to authenticate a web API.

Comment: Can you share some links to understand it better?